# Worried about fire in wall from possible broken wire

Tags: electrical

We used a hair dryer in bedroom outlet. The outlet quit working but breaker didn't trip. The wires inside looked fine, and the plug worked in another spot in the house. Its at the end of a circuit. Possible broken wire in the wall? If I cap the wires could a fire still happen? My wifes not going to sleep well tonight without some reassurance.

Comment: Are the outlets wired using the backstabs?  They are known to fail like this.  If so, change the wiring to the screw terminals.

Comment: Can you post pictures of the outlet wires from all sides? Wires don't just break unless they're physically disturbed. Do you smell anything burnt from the outlet ? Either it's the outlet or a poorly made splice that failed.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that there isn’t a gfci receptacle between the last working receptacle and the dead receptacle?

Comment: The wire/s would need to be capped at the last working power point/receptacle/junction box.  It will be easier to turn off the breaker, have a good nights sleep, and then check connections.

Answer (score 7):

Turn off the circuit breaker and get your rest.

Broken wires between junctions are rare.  The more likely suspects are the outlet itself and the next junction where it's connected, even if that junction has a working outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Remember Occam's Razor. You have three possibilities here:

- Damage to the receptacle or connections in the box you were actually using. *Very high probability.*
- Damage to a connection in another box (usually another receptacle box earlier in the circuit) that was affected by your latest usage. *Small probability.*
- A mouse chose just that moment to chew through the wires in the wall. *Very low probability.*

Hairdryers and similar high power appliances can easily expose wiring flaws that could go undetected for years when a circuit is used with just LED lamps and USB power packs.

Most problems are either in a receptacle or in a connection. Every connection type *can* have problems, but some are more likely than others. In addition, the receptacle itself can fail.

Most likely the problem is at the receptacle you were using. But it is possible that the problem could be at another receptacle in the circuit between the breaker and this receptacle.

- Receptacle

If the receptacle looks damaged in any way - burn marks, cracking, discolored plastic due to excessive heat, etc. - or if when you plug in a device it seems loose, **replace it**. If you're not sure and it is more than a few years old, replace it.

Really. Receptacles are cheap. Get the same basic type (either "regular" or "Decora") but look for good quality. Avoid the $1 (often less) "residential grade" and look for "commercial grade" for typically $2 - $3. The more expensive receptacles are better built and, in particular, often include a plate under the each screw that lets you wire straight in rather than having to make a loop and far more reliable than a "back stab".

- Back Stab Connections

These are single-use connections where you literally stab the wire into the back of the receptacle. They are notoriously unreliable. If you find wires going into the back of the receptacle and *not* under a screw, that's what you have. Replace the receptacle (technically you could reuse the receptacle by putting the wires under the screws, but I don't recommend it) and use the screw terminals (preferably a better receptacle with screw-to-clamp as described above).

- Screw Terminals

These are generally very reliable. However, you have to make sure the wire loop is in the direction that you turn the screws (clockwise), no insulation under the screw and no exposed wire outside the screw.

- Wire Nuts

These are plastic things with metal inside where you connect multiple wires together. You may or may not have any in your receptacle box, depending on many factors. They need to be twisted properly (*very tightly*), with no insulation inside the middle of the wire nut and no visible bare wire outside the wire nut. If any are loose, cracked, etc. replace them.

- Wago Lever-Nuts

These are a relatively new way of connecting wires instead of wire nuts. Unlikely you will find them, but noting them just in case. They are a bit closer to foolproof than wire nuts, but again - no insulation inside, no bare wire outside.

If a thorough evaluation of the problem receptacle, fixing any loose connections, and very likely replacing the receptacle, doesn't solve the problem then you have to start checking other receptacles on the same circuit until you find/fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Get a plug-in receptacle tester and check for correct ground, hot and neutral connections. And check all receptacles on the branch circuit.